# sql_num_rows() not woking giving error in wampserver 2.2

Tags: php, sql, wampserver

Giving error : sql_num_rows().when i click on this link it will send me php website .
I have also tried mysql_fetch_array() both are not working for me.I have to design login page any one can help me with working code in wampserver 2.2.

### login.php

```
<?php
    require ('sql_connect.php');
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `login_users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND      `password` = '$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
            window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
            </SCRIPT>");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
            window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
            </SCRIPT>");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
}
?>
```

### htmllogin.html

```
<html>
<head>
<body bgcolor="">
    <font>
        <center>
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </center>
    </font>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        Username:<input type="text" name="uname">
        Password:<input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="login" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

------------thanks
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/u33Fx.png

Comment: How did you initialized variables `$username` and `$password`?

Comment: why you just do your test in the SQL querry  SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE username = $username AND (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column)) > 0

Comment: $username=mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

Comment: Looks like you if/else blocks aren't being opened and closed consistently which could cause problems unless there is more code your not showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require ('sql_connect.php');
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
    exit();
    }
    else{
     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
    exit();
    }
    }
    else{
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i have also used this.

Comment: change 'username' = '$username' to username = '$username'

Comment: it is also giving error like:mysql_num_rows() with link it is send me to php website

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think you have a Problem in your SQL-Statement:

```
 "SELECT * FROM `login_users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND      `password` = '$password'");
```

Here the ` is wrong. You should remove it, cause it is not used by columns.

And also it can be posible that the apache need to know to work with the php library.

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2-prefork/libphp5.so
```

This is the library sourcetag you have to put in your apache conf file. Also you can test the PHP in your wamp with:

```
 <?php
    phpinfo();
    phpversion();
  ?>
```

This will give you the Version if PHP is active or the PHP as Textfile if not.

So I think that should help. 
Marc

Comment: sir,it is giving php version 5.3.5(2)mysql5.5.8(3)apache2.2.17.          it is not portable in php 5.3.5.so,which method i can use.

Comment: Hi "user3771136",
I think mysql_num_rows should work in php 5.3.5, but if not you can use: 
     mysqli_num_rows()

This is is the version which should be used, cause the other is deprecated, and should not more use in applications. 

Marc

Comment: sir, see the error on this link                                                http://i.stack.imgur.com/u33Fx.png

Comment: i have tried myqli_num_rows()  it is also not working.

Comment: So first of all password is not know in from the Tablestructure. So please check if the column has the same tokens.

Second couse the sql query gives no result the return value from:

     mysql_query

will be false. That is what the second false explains:

So correct the query, column password, (if you send the columns I can do it for you query).

Comment: An other problem is, that you should not use password to find the write user. If password and username is the primary key there should be something wrong in the DB Design.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `login_users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND      `password` = '".$password."'");

OR print your query and then run in mysql directly and check your query is right or wrong

Comment: sir, see the error on this link                                                  http://i.stack.imgur.com/u33Fx.png

Comment: you have to do this
echo "SELECT * FROM `login_users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND      `password` = '$password'";  and then check the value of $password;

Answer (score 0):

So first of all password is not know in the Tablestructure. So please check if the column has the same tokens. 
Second the sql query gives no result the return value from:

mysql_query will be false. That is what the second exception explains.

So correct the query, column password, (if you send the columns I can do it for you query). –  marc hartmann